# ExtJS4 Grid : display objects

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

in my JSON structure I have an object :

```
[{ id: 1, name: xxxxx, operation1: { startdate: 2011-10-25, enddate: 2011-11-25 }, operation2:{......}}]
```

in order to display the operations date, I need to access to stardate and enddate but how ?

I tried

```
{header:'operation1', xtype:'templatecolumn', tpl:'<span>{operation1.startdate}</span>', align:'center'}
```

in fact, I create columns dynamically :

```
for(var i=1;i<=31;i++){
  this.columns.push({header:i, xtype:'templatecolumn', tpl:'<span>{operation'+i+'.startdate}</span>', align:'center'});
}
```

Comment: Typo? The `tpl:'<span>{'+i+'.startdate}</span>'` yields `tpl:'<span>{1.startdate}</span>'`, `tpl:'<span>{2.startdate}</span>'`... etc.

Comment: yes sorry, It's a mistake : `tpl:'<span>{operation'+i+'.startdate}</span>'`

Comment: Problem solved? Could you share a little bit more so we know what's wrong with it :) cheers!

Comment: No, problem isn't solved. I fact, if an user has no operation number 2 for example, It doesn't work. I need to put in Json all operations even they don't exist ?

Comment: Either you set it as empty (to prevent errors), or use [XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate)'s useful methods to do the value checking.

Comment: I set empty values, but Loading, Loading, Loading... and never works.

Comment: my mistake, I forgot a day in the field declaration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you forgot to add `operation1` into your fields. Check out [this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/uWhdb/)

```
fields: ['id', 'name', 'operation1', 'operation2']
```

Comment: I create colums dynamically to create "calendar", check it above.